# Custom Validtion syntax for the IN operator for a column of SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, validation, column-validation

I am trying to find out how can I write a code to restrict a user to enter a value among a set of predefined values (i.e. IN Operator) in a column of a SharePoint list.

[image]

My column name is "Asset type" and I have tried these (below) based on [this](https://support.office.com/en-US/client/results?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=SPOSTANDARD&version=16&omkt=en-US&helpID=FormulaSyntaxError&ver=16&services=EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION%2CFLOW_P2_VIRAL_REAL%2CDYN365_CDS_VIRAL%2CPOWERAPPS_P2_VIRAL%2CFLOW_P2_VIRAL%2CEXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION%2CADALLOM_S_DISCOVERY%2CRMS_S_PREMIUM%2CINTUNE_A%2CRMS_S_ENTERPRISE%2CAAD_PREMIUM%2CMFA_PREMIUM%2CEXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION%2CBI_AZURE_P2%2CEXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION%2CBI_AZURE_P0%2CEXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION%2CDYN365_CDS_VIRAL%2CFLOW_P2_VIRAL%2CMICROSOFTBOOKINGS%2CKAIZALA_O365_P3%2CMICROSOFT_SEARCH%2CWHITEBOARD_PLAN2%2CMIP_S_CLP1%2CMYANALYTICS_P2%2CBPOS_S_TODO_2%2CFORMS_PLAN_E3%2CSTREAM_O365_E3%2CDeskless%2CFLOW_O365_P2%2CPOWERAPPS_O365_P2%2CTEAMS1%2CPROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT%2CSWAY%2CINTUNE_O365%2CYAMMER_ENTERPRISE%2CRMS_S_ENTERPRISE%2COFFICESUBSCRIPTION%2CMCOSTANDARD%2CSHAREPOINTWAC%2CSHAREPOINTENTERPRISE%2CEXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE) in the Formula section.

```
 [Asset type] in ("Innovation","Communication")
 [Asset type]= [Asset type] in ("Innovation","Communication")
 [Asset type]= if([Asset type] in ("Innovation","Communication"), TRUE, FALSE)
[Asset type]= AND(if([Asset type] in ("Innovation"), "Innovation", "Wrong value"), "Similar condition for communication")
 [Asset type]= AND(if([Asset type] in ("Innovation"), "Innovation", FALSE), "Similar condition for communication")
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Sorry, something went wrong
The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OR function in the column validation. Example:

```
=OR([Asset type]="Innovation",[Asset type]="Communication")
```

Comment: it seems this allows user to enter innovation instead of Innovation, is there any way to make this case-sensitive, thx